# Android Custom notification with setOnClickPendingIntent doesn't work on lower version than 3.0. Is there a work around to make it work?

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent, android-2.2-froyo

I'm playing with notification but I was not able to create a notification with a custom layout that works on Froyo (or other android version lower than 3.0) like it works on ICS.

The problem is that I want to associate a pending intent to any single views.

In my opinion there is a work around because the app Notification Toggles do this but I don't know how.

Please help me.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

> I'm playing with notification but I was not able to create a notification with a custom layout that works on Froyo (or other android version lower than 3.0) like it works on ICS.

You can create custom layouts on previous versions, but you cannot respond to their click events reliably.

> The problem is that I want to associate a pending intent to any single views.

That is not supported prior to the rich notifications added in Android 4.1. It may work on some devices, due to manufacturer modifications, but it will not work for all devices.

> In my opinion there is a work around because the app Notification Toggles do this but I don't know how

"Notification Toggles" are part of the device firmware (OS or modifications by manufacturers), not part of an SDK application.

Comment: Everything you said is correct, but Notification Toggles is an application that you can find on Play Store and If you install it on Gingerbread or Froyo device you can click on a single toggle of a notification with more than one toggle. I don't know how it works but is work around is perfect.

Comment: @Meroelyth: And therefore it is not a notification. They are using other techniques for appearing to be part of the notification drawer. I repeat: a notification cannot reliably respond to click events on widgets in a custom view prior to the rich notifications added in Android 4.1.

Comment: It is a notification. Please try it.

Comment: @Meroelyth: No, it is a system alert window. You can tell this by reading the Play Store listing. "SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW - necessary on Android 2.x for detecting which toggle was clicked". I say it again: a notification cannot reliably respond to click events on widgets in a custom view prior to the rich notifications added in Android 4.1.

Comment: Oh...many thanks. SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW can be a work around to do what I'm trying to do? Do you can link me a tutorial on how to use it?

Comment: @Meroelyth: "SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW can be a work around to do what I'm trying to do?" -- presumably, though I do not endorse its usage. "Do you can link me a tutorial on how to use it?" -- no, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Notification Toggles uses a completely different way of triggering things for Android below 3.0. I had to solve the problem myself too.

Their way (which I used too) is to create an invisible 1x1 pixel system window which intercepts all clicks including those outside the window, grab their X coordinate and then pass the click event unchanged:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    x = event.getRawX();
    return false;
}
```

Then when some click fires your ContentIntent (and you know the X coordinate of that click) you calculate what to do.

Answer (score 0):

GingerBread expects a ContentIntent. So I added a dummy pending intent like :

```
        pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Notification notification =  new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setAutoCancel(true)
                                        .setContentTitle(userString)
                                        .setContentText("Queued")
                                        .setContentIntent(pi)
                                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.stat_sys_download_done)
                                        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                                        .setTicker(tickerText)
                                        .build();
```